# How to avoid this WARN service=EJB3 is unconfigured, using legacy resolve? JBoss5.2

Tags: warnings, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, jboss5.x

**Environment:**

- java 7
- javaee 6
- jboss eap 5.2
- EJB3

WARN [org.jboss.injection.EJBRemoteHandler]
EJBTHREE-1828: EJBInjectionContainer jboss.j2ee:ear=name.ear,jar=backend.jar,name=ClassNameService,service=EJB3 is unconfigured, using legacy resolve

**EJB**

```
@Stateless
@Local({NameSessionLocal.class})
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "es.domain.app.ClassNameService")
public class ClassNameService implements NameSessionLocal {

    @EJB(name = "es.domain.app.CenterSession")
    private CenterSessionLocal centerMgr;
...
```

**CenterSession.java**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "es.domain.app.CenterSession")
public class CenterSession implements CenterSessionLocal {
...
```

How can I avoid this message?

Comment: It looks like if it were a Bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-3834

Comment: Avoidable with ctx.lookup("es.domain.app.CenterSession")